# ASP.Net How to save file name in database using "uploadify" plugin

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, c#-4.0

i am using jquery uploadify plugin in my project to upload multiple files and save the file in a floder.
i have done the basic things (on upload file is saving in the folder)
now in my requirement i also need to save those file name into my database

below are the code that i have used in my project
in my FileUpload.aspx page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(
        function () {
            $("#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID %>").fileUpload({
                'uploader': 'scripts/uploader.swf',
                'cancelImg': 'images/cancel.png',
                'buttonText': 'Browse',
                'script': 'Upload.ashx',
                'folder': '../images',
                'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
                'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
                'multi': true,
                'auto': false
            });
        }
    );
```

```
 <div style="padding: 40px">
     <a href="javascript:$('#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>').fileUploadStart()">Start Upload</a>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
</div>
```

and i am writing code for it in Upload.ashx.cs page like this

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
 {
     context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
     //context.Response.Write("Hello World");
     context.Response.Expires = -1;
     try
     {
         HttpPostedFile postedFile = context.Request.Files["Filedata"];
         string sDirectory = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@context.Request["folder"]);
         string savepath = "";
         string tempPath = "";
         tempPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FolderPath"];
         savepath = context.Server.MapPath(tempPath);
         string filename = postedFile.FileName;
         if (!Directory.Exists(savepath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(savepath);
         postedFile.SaveAs(sDirectory + @"\" + filename);
         string fullpath = savepath + @"\" + filename;
         context.Response.Write(tempPath + "/" + filename);
         context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        context.Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }

}
```

now i want to save upload file name in database and it code should be on fileupload.aspx.cs page so that i can use "Upload.ashx.cs" page many times.

Comment: why can't you just save filename into db from `Upload.ashx.cs` ?

Comment: yes,i can do it but now i want to use Upload.ashx.cs in many other web page application and having different table in db for different page. i am thinking to just call Upload.ashx.cs page in script of all the pages where i need upload.

Comment: you can use some kind of flag like `ifSaveToDB` to be send from uploadify  `scriptData` parameter and then accesing using `context.Request["ifSaveToDB"]` to know whether to save or not